# Why is my eevee viewport render acting like this? also; upon rendering the result is transparent

Tags: rendering, 3d-view

Lately my viewport render on eevee is fine and shows the textures and everything, but this time, when I open blender even if its 2.83 or 2.9 or 2.91 the problem still the same and gives me gray texture, and upon rendering the result is transparent.

I checked my Film settings if i set it to transparent and its not, i don't know how to fix this.

[image]

note: when I switch to cycles render everything's fine

Comment: Latest AMD Drivers are the cause. Roll back to previous driver version to fix it.